# Where is a quick commit button in IntelliJ Idea New UI

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

The current UI (which will become old soon) in IntelliJ Idea has buttons aside from the build for fetch and commit. I am interested in the latter one that opens a modal window and I can select items for commit.

[image]

I don't know if this feature was there since my first installation by default, however, it is gone now and the whole toolbar seems emptier.

The [New UI](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/new-ui/) does not have it.

[image]

[image]

Where is the commit button in the new UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out that the whole bar can be customized just by right-mouse clicking and selecting `Add to Main Toolbar`.

[image]

Upon selecting a few, the option `Customize Toolbar...` opens a modal window through which you can order the icons on both the left and right sides and add separators between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can find commit button in this image]

The commit button is on the left-top of screen.
I attached the detailed image.
You can find commit button in this image.

Comment: Nah, it didn’t appear there. I update the question with another picture.

Comment: Could you share your IDE screen? I cannot see any update image.